# Creating edges based on vertices IDs spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to basically join two RDDs vertices and edges. Vertices and edges are created using the following code:

```
val file = sc.textFile("file.gz") //This tab separated file has more than two columns among which only first two columns with source and destination URL are relevant 

val edges= file.flatMap(f => {
  val urls = f.split("\t")
  if (!(urls.length < 2)) 
{ Some(urls(0) +"\t"+ urls(1)) }
else None }).distinct

val vertices = edges.flatMap(f => f.split("\t")).distinct 
val vertices_zip = vertices.zipWithUniqueId
```

Now I have a list of vertices (URLs) with IDs generated using using the above method like:

```
google.de/2011/10/Extract-host,11
facebook.de/2014/11/photos,28         
community.cloudera.com/t5/,42         
facebook.de/2020/11/photos,91
```

I would like to create edges based on these IDs. Edges RDD file is tab separated like below:

```
google.de/2011/10/Extract-host   facebook.de/2014/11/photos   
facebook.de/2014/11/photos       community.cloudera.com/t5/,42
community.cloudera.com/t5/       google.de/2011/10/Extract-host
```

Required result:

```
11     28
28     42
42     11
```

I tried the following code

```
val edges_id = edges.flatMap( line => line.split( "\t" ) ).map( line => ( line,0) ) .join(vert_zip).map(x=>x._2._2)
```

But not getting the desired result. I am getting

```
11
28
28
42
42
11
```

I am not sure how to join the edges with the vertices RDD to get this result. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: `Edges RDD are tab separated like below`. RDD's are not tab separated. do you mean that you have file that is tab separated? And can you post the procedure/code that you used for creating vetices rdd and edges rdd? I think a simple lookup map would solve your issue

Comment: @RameshMaharjan I hope it is clear now

Comment: I have answered below :) please check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `zipWithUniqueId`, then *collect the rdds as map* and then *use that map to get the indexes in the edges rdd* as following

```
val vertices_zip = vertices.zipWithUniqueId.collectAsMap

val edges_id = edges.map(f => {
  val urls = f.split("\t")
  vertices_zip(urls(0))+"\t"+vertices_zip(urls(1))
})
```

Thats all. I hope the answer is helpful

**Updated**

you commented

> > I am getting an exception : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

for that you can *use broadcast which would call required rdds to the executors memory instead of all the map*

```
val vertices_zip = sc.broadcast(vertices.zipWithUniqueId.collectAsMap)

val edges_id = edges.map(f => {
  val urls = f.split("\t")
  vertices_zip.value(urls(0))+"\t"+vertices_zip.value(urls(1))
})
```

## joins

You've commented again

> > Is it possible to change the code I tried above to get the result (the one with the join)?

join way would require two joins meaning that two shuffles would be needed to get the desired result

```
val vertices_zip = vertices.zipWithUniqueId

val edges_id = edges.map(line => {
  val splitted = line.split("\t")
  (splitted(0), splitted(1))
})
  .join(vertices_zip)
  .map(_._2)
  .join(vertices_zip)
  .map(x => x._2._1+"\t"+x._2._2)
```

Comment: It is not working. I am getting an exception : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Is it possible to change the code I tried above to get the result (the one with the join)?

Comment: Yes I did. But my job got aborted.